# Why printf() after the while loop would not work?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

I'm a beginner and I've recently started learning C and here is an example in "*The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie*" that I don't understand. This program is supposed to count new lines in input and print out the final result. This is the exact same program that is in the book (page 19). The output of it is nothing. I can input forever and it just goes to a new line...

```
main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

If I put the "printf("%d\n", nl)" statement in the body of the if statement, the output would be printed each time on a new line and the value of "nl" wouldn't reset either. it just increments every time I input something and the program wouldn't terminate.

Why doesn't the example work?

Comment: You need to *send a newline* to your program. For macOS or Linux hit Ctrl-D. For Windows hit Ctrl-Z.

Comment: how is it supposed to detect EOF?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @johnelemans I didn't write the "#include <stdio.h>" part in here... my mistake, sorry...

Comment: @iBug Do you mean EOF, rather than newline?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
  return 0;
}
```

I ran it on my computer using Code::Blocks and it worked just fine. maybe you just forgot the int before main and return 0 ^^

Comment: If you're going to nitpick ISO C conformance, it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: No, that was not the issue. I'm on windows and apparently after typing some words and new lines I need to hit Ctrl+Z to break the loop. And as far as I know, the int before main() , in simple programs like this, is not that much necessary; the program would work just fine...